# Is there any method to get the number of rows and columns present in .xlsx sheet using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Is there any method to get the number of rows and columns present in .xlsx sheet using openpyxl ? 
In xlrd,

```
     sheet.ncols 
     sheet.nrows
```

would give the column and row count. 
Is there any such method in openpyxl ?

Comment: `sheet.max_row` `sheet.max_column` `cell.row` `cell.column` `cell.column_letter`

Answer (score 30):

Given a variable `sheet`, determining the number of rows and columns can be done in one of the following ways:

#### Version ~= 3.0.10 Syntax

```
rows = sheet.max_row
columns = sheet.max_column
```

#### Version ~= 3.0.5 Syntax

```
rows = sheet.max_rows
columns = sheet.max_column
```

#### Version 1.x.x Syntax

```
rows = sheet.nrows
columns = sheet.ncols
```

#### Version 0.x.x Syntax

```
rows = sheet.max_row
columns = sheet.max_column
```

Comment: It contained out-of-date and inaccurate information, which is why it was edited.

Comment: @virtualxtc it's max_row not plural, you also need to check if you're using v1 and thus need brows?

Comment: no - was just a stupid error on my end.  Thanks though.

Comment: Not working for me. `writer.sheets['Sheet1']` how not `max_row` and neither `nrows`

Comment: Look like it's for xlrd not for openpyxl

Comment: in fact i don't know how he has 19 upvotes

Comment: @ElMaestroDeToMare definitely worked for me when I wrote this answer, but do note it was half a decade ago and the library has now gone through four major versions!

Comment: I'm using openpyxl=3.0.10, and for me it's `sheet.max_row`, not "rows".

Comment: Thanks @Joe, can't believe that they're still updating the syntax!  We're now back to the 0.0.x syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Worksheet has these methods: 'dim_colmax', 'dim_colmin', 'dim_rowmax', 'dim_rowmin'

Below is a small example:

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("some_excel.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[RESULTS_SHEET_NAME]

last_row = worksheet.dim_rowmax
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt know about the attributes `.dim_rowmax` (also for min/max and col/row). Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Building upon Dani's solution and not having enough reputation to comment in there. I edited the code by adding a manual piece of control to reduce the time consumed on searching

```
## iteration to find the last row with values in it
nrows = ws.max_row
if nrows > 1000:
    nrows = 1000

lastrow = 0
while True:
    if ws.cell(nrows, 3).value != None:
        lastrow = nrows
        break
    else:
        nrows -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the logic

```
    number_of_rows = sheet_obj.max_row
    last_row_index_with_data = 0
    
    while True:
        if sheet_obj.cell(number_of_rows, 3).value != None:
            last_row_index_with_data = number_of_rows
            break
        else:
            number_of_rows -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using Pandas to get all sheets row and column counts. It uses `df.shape` to get the counts.

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')
sheetnames = xl.sheet_names  # get sheetnames
for sheet in sheetnames:
    df = xl.parse(sheet)
    dimensions = df.shape
    print('sheetname', ' --> ', sheet)
    print(f'row count on "{sheet}" is {dimensions[0]}')
    print(f'column count on "{sheet}" is {dimensions[1]}')
    print('-----------------------------')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import xlrd

location = ("Filelocation\filename.xlsx")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(location)
s1 = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
s1.cell_value(0,0)                       #initializing cell from the cell position  

print(" No. of rows: ", s1.nrows)             
print(" No. of columns: ", s1.ncols)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need the number of **non-empty cols**, the more efficient I've found is
Take care it gives the number of NON-EMPTY columns, not the total number of columns. When I say the more efficient, I mean the easiest way to achieve the goal, but not the fastest (I did not test execution speed).
in the following, `sheet` is an instance of `openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet`:

```
values = list(sheet.values) #values is a list of tuple of same len
nb_cols = len(values[0])
```

if I need the number of non-empty lines, I do this:

```
nb_lines = len([v for v in sheet.values if any(v)])
```

Notice this last instruction can fail : if a line has only 0, it is considered as empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
import openpyxl as ox
from openpyxl import Workbook

path=("test.xlsx") #location of the file
workbook=ox.load_workbook(path) 
sheet=workbook.active     
nrows=sheet.max_row       #openpyxl version of nrows of xlrd
ncols=sheet.max_column    #openpyxl version of ncols of xlrd 
print(nrows,ncols)
```