# How to write to new empty cell in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I see there are a few similar questions already asked, but none seem to solve my problem. Also, some offer deprecated solutions such as using coordinate.

The code I have works fine, but because I start the loop at a certain position, every time I re-run the code, it obviously starts writing from that one position. I'm looking for the most pythonic and up-to-date solution to this.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

```
import openpyxl

roster = openpyxl.load_workbook('Path/To/File/roster.xlsx')
sheet = roster.active

counter = 7
while counter < 1000:
    counter +=1
    fname = input("Enter first name: ").capitalize().strip()
    lname = input("Enter last name: ").capitalize().strip()
    grade = int(input("Enter grade: "))
    attendance = int(input("Enter atendance: "))

    for row in sheet.rows:
        sheet[f'A{counter}'] = f'{counter}'
        sheet[f'B{counter}'] = fname
        sheet[f'C{counter}'] = lname
        sheet[f'D{counter}'] = grade
        sheet[f'E{counter}'] = attendance

roster.save('Path/To/File/roster.xlsx')
```

Comment: from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408339/is-there-any-method-to-get-the-number-of-rows-and-columns-present-in-xlsx-sheet/35408471) maybe you need to set `counter = sheet.max_rows` before while loop

Comment: Just use `ws.append()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max_row` and [append](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.append) from openpyxl.worksheet.

```py
counter = sheet.max_row
while counter < 1000:
    fname = input("Enter first name: ").capitalize().strip()
    lname = input("Enter last name: ").capitalize().strip()
    grade = int(input("Enter grade: "))
    attendance = int(input("Enter atendance: "))

    sheet.append([counter, fname, lname, grade, attendance])
    counter += 1
```

Comment: Might as well just use `while True` with a break condition.

Comment: @HALF9000 Thank you so much. I didn't know about append and max_row. That worked perfectly!